# p5.js how to freeze canvas?

Tags: javascript, processing, p5.js

I try to do something like that :

```js
function setup() {
  createCanvas(500, 250);
  //frameRate(1);
}

function draw() {
  background(50, 50, 150);
  
  translate(10, 10);
  for (let i = 0; i < 30; i++) {
    rect(i*15, 0, 10, random(30, 120));
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/0.5.11/p5.min.js"></script>
```

But i want to "freeze" this canvas, so if i load the page i will have 30 rect() at a random height between 30 and 120.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

One option would be to use `noLoop()` method inside `setup` function that will stop `draw` method loop.

```js
function setup() {
  createCanvas(500, 250);
  noLoop()
}

function draw() {
  background(50, 50, 150);

  translate(10, 10);
  for (let i = 0; i < 30; i++) {
    rect(i * 15, 0, 10, random(30, 120));
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/0.5.11/p5.min.js"></script>
```

Note that with using `noLoop` and `loop` methods, you can toggle draw loop on some event for example `mousePressed` like this.

```js
let stop = true;

function setup() {
  const canvas = createCanvas(500, 250);
  if(stop) noLoop();
  canvas.mousePressed(function() {
    stop = !stop;
    stop ? noLoop() : loop()
  })
}

function draw() {
  background(50, 50, 150);

  translate(10, 10);
  for (let i = 0; i < 30; i++) {
    rect(i * 15, 0, 10, random(30, 120));
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/0.5.11/p5.min.js"></script>
```

Other option is to create bars array once in `setup` function and then show them with `draw` method. This way you don't have to stop `draw` loop.

```js
const bars = []
class Bar {
  constructor(x, y, w, h) {
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    this.w = w;
    this.h = h;
  }
  show() {
    rect(this.x, this.y, this.w, this.h);
  }
}

function setup() {
  createCanvas(500, 250);
  for (let i = 0; i < 30; i++) {
    bars.push(new Bar(i * 15, 0, 10, random(30, 120)))
  }
}

function draw() {
  background(50, 50, 150);
  translate(10, 10);
  bars.forEach(bar => bar.show())
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/0.5.11/p5.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: thanx for your reply :D

Comment: You're welcome, note that you can also toggle loop like this https://jsfiddle.net/tvj04wym/7/

Comment: Nice answer. A third option would be to use the `createGraphics()` function to create a buffer, and draw to that once.

Answer (score 3):

Since i was looking for a way to simply freeze the canvas and this post was the first that came up i thought i leave the solution here.

you could use this with an extra incrementor for the number of rectangles which then triggers noLoop()

From [the p5 docs](https://p5js.org/reference/#/p5/noLoop)

freezing the canvas by holding down any mouse button

```
function mousePressed() {
  noLoop();
}

function mouseReleased() {
  loop();
}
```

Answer (score -1):

A solution would be to set another draw function which is empty. I don't know exactly how p5 works, perhaps they clear the canvas anyways. But here is a possible solution:

```
function draw() {
    //drawing stuff
}

function freezeCanvas() {
    draw = function(){}
}
```